# Mid-transaction control with the Square API

Tags: square-connect

Is it possible to modify a sales transaction on the square app via the API before it results in a sale?  I'd like to add an item to a transaction via the API based on certain conditions (eg: particular customers get a free item).  It appears the API supports only 1) collecting detail of transactions already completed, OR 2) creation of entire transactions, based on basically creating your own the square app.  I was hoping to build something simple with the API, intercepting transactions as they are created by the ipad square app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the ability to modify a transaction on the Point of Sale app using our APIs isn't available.